# No way to move pound (£) symbol in UNIX?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Need get  the delimiters at the starting of each line, below are sample input and output files for reference. In actual Delimiter used are(  `£{`, `^$^`)
Note - The file to be rearranged has huge data

Have tried the below but it does not work:

```
tr £{ \\n
sed 's/£{/\n/g' 
awk '{ gsub("£{", "\n") } 1'
```

**Input File:**

```
 £{firstlinecontinues£{secondstartsfromhereandit
  keepsoncontinueingtillend£{herecomes3rdand£{fi
  nallyfourthisalsohere
```

**Output File:**

```
£{firstlinecontinues
£{secondstartsfromhereanditkeepsoncontinueingtillend
£{herecomes3rdand
£{finallyfourthisalsohere
```

Comment: Does this duplicate your question? [Rearrange special character using AWK command or ksh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713572/rearrange-special-character-using-awk-command-or-ksh-script)

Comment: not completely but partially yes, I am still looking for solution.

Comment: These  strange delimiters might be an indication of another underlying problem.  Does this work for you?  `echo "£{1£{2£{3" | sed 's/£{/\n&/g'`  If so, you may have an issue with your data file.

Comment: nope this too does not work, the file generated is without any change, the below command partially works for me but I am unable to print the delimiter at starting of each line

awk '{ gsub("\£{", "\n") } 1'

Comment: There is no file here, just a pair of commands to create (if successful) three lines from the given input which is part of it.

Comment: sorry have got the output - 
```£{1
   £{2
   £{3```

Comment: in separate lines?  If so, it should work on your data file as well.

Comment: yes in separate lines not sure why I am not able to paste in the comment one after another in new line

Comment: @karafka `sed 's/£{/\n&/g'` this is not working for the data file :(

Comment: You can now see that the problem is not with the script but your data file.  Not sure if anyone can help you with that.

Comment: checkin that, would you please modify your earlier solution please, these script only searches for delimiter at starting of file, can this be modified to search delimiter at any position in the file ``awk -v mark='${' -v c=2 'index($0,mark) {++i} 
                                                                                                      {print > ("file."int((i-1)/c+1))}' file``

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s`:

```
$ awk -v RS='£{' 'NR>1{gsub(/\s/,""); print RS $0}' file
£{firstlinecontinues
£{secondstartsfromhereanditkeepsoncontinueingtillend
£{herecomes3rdand
£{finallyfourthisalsohere
```

Comment: Glad for your response, I tried running the command but ended up with no output and the file remains unchanged, there is no error though

Comment: Can anyone please give a response, I am badly stuck due to this

Comment: The command isn't intended to modify the file, it will produce output as you can see it does in my answer. If it's producing no output then either a) your real input doesn't look like the sample in your question (specifically you have no lines that contain `£{`) or, b) you copy/pasted my script incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="(£{\|\^\$\^)"; OFS=ORS=""}{$1=$1;print $0 (FNR>1?"\n":"") RT}' file
```

Comment: thanks for this but It does not shifts the delimiters to the next line as showed in the output file

Comment: It actually compresses the file instead of creating new line Starting with the delimiter

Comment: This works in my environment ; `GNU Awk 4.1.4` and Bash = `4.4.12(1)-release`

Answer (score 0):

Since the £ symbol is represented by two Octal codes, 302 and 243, I was able to produce the desired result with this perl command:

```
perl -pe 's/(\302\243)/\n$1/g' data.txt
```

NOTE: Here's what I see on my system:

```
echo "£" | od -c
0000000 302 243  \n
0000003
```